# How to Store data in Redis OM for node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I am struggling to use Redis for my NodeJs application.
In my Mysql database, I have all country names, cities, postal codes. It has thousands of records . So it takes so many time to search cities through my application. As a solution for that, we found Redis OM for node js. It can fix the solution, But the problem is that to store data in Redis in the initial state.
I have a large dataset, so using `createEntity` takes so long since it should go with a loop.

```
const {Client, Entity, Schema, Repository} = require('redis-om');
const addressSchema = require('./bm_redis_schema.js');
const client = new Client();

let data = select query 
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                const singleAddress = addressRepository.createEntity();
                
                singleAddress.id = i;
                singleAddress.state_id = data[i].state_id;
                singleAddress.state_name = data[i].state_name;
                singleAddress.state_code = data[i].state_code;
                singleAddress.country_id = data[i].country_id;
                singleAddress.country_name = data[i].country_name;
    
                const enitiyID = await addressRepository.save(singleAddress);  //Save all data to the Redis DB

               
            }
```

Please help If i'm doing this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation with my NodeJS application, Redis-OM does not seem be a good fit for loading large amounts of data into Redis. The solution I'm currently working on implementing is to use Redis Streams to load the initial state.

I'm still reading up on Streams but the idea is that I push the data into a stream that is monitored my a consumergroup and the consumergroup has multiple consumers. Each consumer takes a record from the group and writes it via Redis-OM. So if you assign 3 consumers to the consumergroup for your input stream, then 3x write can be achieved. You could also split up the read part by creating 3 functions that each read 1/3 of the data filter by postal code. Each instance is reading it's portion of the db and writing to a stream, so you have 3x reading to the stream, then the consumergroups/consumers writing to Redis at 3x.

This is the concept I'm currently working on implementing. My data is a large json file, not a db though. Redis-OM seems to be great for reading/writing for the frontend such as user data or user searches, but again it doe seem great for the initial seeding of the Redis instance.

Hope this is helpful. I'm a bit new to Redis and NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you for your idea.. I will investigate Redis stream for my project as well.